# How do I make an image start at the bottom of it's container?

Tags: html, css, image, overflow, hidden

I have a tall image inside a short container with `overflow: hidden;`. The bottom of the image is cut off. How do I make the top get cut off instead of the bottom?

[image: dramatized]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

give the container the following css:

```
position:relative;
```

and the image the following css:

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
```

P.S. 
Very nice (and clear) illustrations btw

Comment: +1, since you answered with pretty much the same answer as I was about to submit! =) May I offer you the demo I was working on: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/47Qne/1/).

Comment: I seriously don't get how I went from +1 to -2 to 0 to +2 in 5 minutes O_o

Comment: @David Thomas Whoa! Awesome demo! (might be a bit overkill) but still very nicely done!

Comment: Well, for what it's worth the down-votes appear to have been revoked...leaving only two up-votes...

Comment: @David Thomas lol weirdest voting on an answer I've ever received XD

Comment: If it's worth doing, it's worth *over-doing*! =)

Comment: I dream to understand why the hell so many people are on this site just to be downvoting without explanation.

Answer (score 3):

If your image is just the `background-image` of the container, do this way:

```
#container {
    background: url(your-image.jpg) no-repeat bottom left;
}
```

Otherwise, position the `img` element to the bottom of the container, like @Joseph suggested:

```
#container {
    position:relative;
}

#container img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Ok great, thanks. I have HTML like this: `<div id="container"><img ...></div>` so the second method is the one that applies. 

Making it the background might be a bit more concise but that would be pretty hard given that it's a Drupal View

Answer (score 0):

If the container has a 300px height for example, this works:

```
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```